# scons pass arguments to a particular step

Tags: command-line-arguments, scons, argument-passing

I have a very complex scons project. One of the targets include running a unittest application that is generated as part of the build.

I would like to be able to say:

```
scons <target> <some magic: arguments>
```

where `some magic` is something that will tell scons for which execution step the arguments are and the `arguments` are completely arbitrary arguments that the unittest application knows how to interpret.

the question is, is there already mechanism to do this, or I need to add code in my scons to achieve this - in both cases a pointers how to do it will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the User Guide at http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html . You'll be interested in chapter 10 "Controlling a Build From the Command Line", which describes ways how to propagate values from the command-line to your SConscripts.
Reserve an Environment Variable, e.g. "UNITTST_ARGS", and use it to transport your arguments through to your SConscript, where you actually call your external unittest application.